# why am I not seeing "unit test success" section of "unit tests coverage" widget in SonarQube

Tags: unit-testing, karma-runner, sonarqube

I am following this tutorial - http://blog.dasberg.nl/getting-your-frontend-code-quality-in-order/ - to push the front end quality metrics to SonarQube. I was able to reuse the coverage report generated by Karma in Sonar but I don't see the section for "unit test success" at all. 
This is how it looks in the sonar4.2 on my workstation

[image: unit test coverage widget]

and this is my sonar properties file

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=org.rj.js:javascript-build-process
sonar.projectName=javascript-build-process
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.sources=src/js
# Language
sonar.language=js
# Encoding of sources files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
sonar.junit.reportsPath=coverage/junit
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=coverage/PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X)/lcov.info
sonar.verbose=true
```

Also the log doesn't show any warnings or errors. Am i missing anything else here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed since SonarQube JavaScript PLugin version 1.5 it is not possible to import unit test results. See section [Release Note](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/JavaScript+Plugin) in SonarQube documentation.

This feature might be reintroduce in future version.

Comment: Indeed, there are great chances that this feature will be reintroduced sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking at this post, this feature was re-introduced in version 2.2. It should work exactly the same way as it did before it was removed in version 1.5.

https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJS-239